# My view slides up completely when my cellphone keyboard opens

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have my view that when I open the keyboard of my cell phone it totally moves with everything and my top bar, what I need from my app that contains a chat is that the top bar is fixed and that only when the keyboard is opened do the messages move.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:HomieApp.Views.Common;assembly=HomieApp"
             xmlns:app="clr-namespace:HomieApp;assembly=HomieApp"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:HomieApp.Helpers;assembly=HomieApp"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms" 
             x:Class="HomieApp.Views.Servicio.ChatPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="leftChatTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <common:ChatLeftMessageItemTemplate />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="rightChatTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <common:ChatRightMessageItemTemplate />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <helpers:ChatDataTemplateSelector x:Key="chatDataTemplateSelector"
                                              LeftChatTemplate="{StaticResource leftChatTemplate}"
                                              RightChatTemplate="{StaticResource rightChatTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <common:MainLabelNavigation 
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            x:Name="bar"
            IsVisibleMenu="True"
                                    Clicked="Bar_OnClicked"></common:MainLabelNavigation>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListView
            x:Name="ListViewMensajes"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Mensajes}"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            SeparatorColor="Transparent"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource chatDataTemplateSelector}">
            </ListView>

            <!--- BUTTONS CONTAINER  -->
            <Grid 
            x:Name="ContainerSend"
            Grid.Row="2" 
            ColumnSpacing="5"
            Padding="0"
            MinimumHeightRequest="40">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <app:GradientButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                    VerticalOptions="End" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               Command="{Binding EnviarVideoCommand}"
                                    ButtonType="Gray"
                                    Text="Tomar Video"/>

                <app:GradientButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                               VerticalOptions="End" 
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               Command="{Binding EnviarImagenCommand}"
                                    ButtonType="Gray"
                               Text="Tomar Foto"/>


                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             Margin="0,0,0,15"
                         BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource TranslucidOrange }" 
                         Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--- ENTRY  -->
                    <Entry 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje..."
                    Text="{Binding Path=Mensaje, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <!--- SEND BUTTON  -->
                    <app:FontAwesomeIcon
                    x:Name="SendButton"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Margin="10,0"
                    Text="{ x:Static app:Icon.FAPlay }"
                    FontSize="20"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource BorderTextColor}"
                    Style="{ StaticResource FontIcon }"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>

            </Grid>

            <app:CustomActivityIndicator
            IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</ContentPage>
```

I already try changing the views in various ways, but since I am new to the development of applications in Xamarin I still do not understand or understand the view they handle very well.

Comment: You want to fix the top bar when the keyborad open? Your top bar is a custom view and added to the contentPage, you have to detect the keyboard open/close event and keep the position in relevant method.

Comment: dig in this direction: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/05/showing-keyboard-options-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Hi, not exactly that. At the top of my view is my navigation bar, and every time you open the cellphone's keypad it goes up with all the other views, users do not know that pressing outside the keyboard returns or pressing the close button on the keyboard , so I require that my navigation bar be fixed every time the keyboard is opened.

Comment: https://homieapp.blob.core.windows.net/fotos/FotoPerfil_304_12072019120002.png

Comment: https://homieapp.blob.core.windows.net/fotos/FotoPerfil_255_12072019120051.png

Comment: In the first photo my normal chat is shown, in the second it is shown with the keyboard open, causing the whole view to slide up.